# Download files with zend contextSwitch() Action Helper

Tags: zend-framework, controller, action, helper, context-switch

everybody. I'm stack with similar thing: i have to provide a download file capability with Zend Framework... Several hours of googling don't help me with this... 
So here is my Controller code (note: i'm a beginner):

```
//callback
public function sendFile()
{
    readfile(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public/pdf/10.pdf");
}

public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->contextSwitch()
            ->addContext('file', array(
                  'headers' => array(
                      'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                      'Content-disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="10.pdf"'),
                  'callbacks' => array(
                      'init'  => '_sendFile'
                  )
              ))
            ->addActionContext('download', 'file')
            ->setAutoJsonSerialization(false)
            ->initContext();

}
// ...
public function downloadAction()
{
}
```

PS: I find this [download files with zend framework](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/05/25/download-files-with-zend-framework/) but i want to do this Zend way.
Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You could try.

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->contextSwitch()
            ->addContext('file'))
            ->addActionContext('download', 'file')
            ->setAutoJsonSerialization(false)
            ->initContext();

}
// ...
public function downloadAction()
{
    if ($this->_helper->contextSwitch()->getCurrentContext() == 'file') {
        $this->getResponse()
                ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf; charset=binary')
                ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="10.pdf"')
                ->setHeader('Content-length', filesize(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public/pdf/10.pdf"))
                ->setHeader('Cache-control', 'private');
        readfile(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public/pdf/10.pdf");
        $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    } else {
        throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('File not found', 404);
    }
}
```

You must also set the parameter **format** to **file** either as a POST or GET variable in the calling page, for example.

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/path/to/controller/format/file">
```

If your file is in your public documents folder you could just simply link to it directly.

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/pdf/10.pdf">
```

and not bother with the above PHP/ZF code.

I hope this helps.

Kind regards

Garry

Comment: Big thank you, @Garry ! You approach successfully works! But why zend dev people advice to do it via callbacks? [contextSwitch() callbacks](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch) Many thanks for quick answer)

Comment: And more one thing: if i do it via own callback ($this->sendFile()) - it start to output raw pdf file body to browsers window... Why it doing that. Where is problem?

Comment: @andrew I have made some changs to the code above, this works for me.

Comment: maybe i missed filesize() to the Content-length header and it shows me raw data... H-m-m. But anyway, thank you, very much, @Garry !